# Declaration inside class or outside?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

Given the following functions:

1)

```
IntMatrix operator+(const IntMatrix &matrix, int scalar);
```

2)

```
IntMatrix operator+(int scalar, const IntMatrix &matrix);
```

Which take a scalar and adds it to every member in the Matrix, Should I declare them outside the class (like what is shown above) or inside my class?

In collage they thought as that if we need it to work in both directions **(symmetrical behaviour)** we declare it out but here it's a little bit complicated...

Answer (score 1):

Function 1 can be written inside the class, as a member function, but function 2 must be written as a non-member function, since the left hand side is not a `IntMatrix`.

I would suggest writing a `operator+=` that takes an `int` as a member function. Then you can easily call that from both `operator+`, which you can write as non-members.

So your `operator+` (as non-members) would look like this:

```
IntMatrix operator+(IntMatrix matrix, int scalar) {
  return matrix += scalar;
}

IntMatrix operator+(int scalar, IntMatrix matrix) {
  return matrix += scalar;
}
```

Comment: I have operator+= written inside my class and used it in the imlementation

Comment: your code is wrong since you are making changes on matrix

Comment: Good, then you can have both `operator+` as non-members.

Comment: Free functions can be declared inside a class too (`friend`).

Comment: @eerorika True, but there's no reason to grant friendship here, so I avoid it unless necessary.